# Get event or HTML object for any date in calendar

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to set the color for some existing dates in a calendar.
I know how to set background color for a date.

I am using this code if I select a date manually `onclick= 'fSetSelectedDayShow(this)'`.

```
function fSetSelectedDayShow(evnt){
    var selectedDate=evnt.firstChild.innerHTML; 
    evnt.style.backgroundColor = '#66FF66';
}
```

This is working fine if I select any date manually from my calendar.

Now I want vice versa. I have dates and I want to set the color in the calendar.

For example, I want to color the 9th, 11th and 13th dates of calendar while loading the screen. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has little to do with JavaScript events. Your example of

```
onclick='fSetSelectedDayShow(this)'
```

is not a real JavaScript event handler, but a user function that is wrapped into an anonymous event handler when the onlclick event fires like

```
function(evt) {
  return fSetSelectedDayShow(evt.originalTarget);
}
```

To achieve the coloring of specific days in your calendar, I would simply use CSS. Most likely you use some kind of server side code or JavaScript to render you page, so you could conditionally add some value to the `class` attibute to the tags of those days you wish to color.

An example of this using PHP to render your HTML could be:

```
<div class="calendarDay <?php echo in_array(date('d', $timestamp), array(9, 11, 13)) ? 'colorThis' : '' ?>">
  <?php echo date('d', $timestamp) ?>
</div>
```

Then obviously you need a CSS class like:

```
.colorThis {
  background-color: #66FF66;
}
```